# List remote branches - git branch -a vs git ls-remote --heads origin

Tags: git, github

Following [post](https://tecadmin.net/list-all-remote-branches-in-git/#) commands should produce the same output with regard to remote branches, however

```
git fetch
git branch -a
```

shows remote branches that are not visible while executing

```
git ls-remote --heads origin
```

What is the reason of this behavior?

[clarification]

```
(TA216441) $ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/TA216441'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

(TA216441) $ git fetch
(TA216441) $ git branch -a
* TA216441
  TA216442
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/TA212425
  remotes/origin/TA216441
  remotes/origin/TA219346
  remotes/origin/TA220305
  remotes/origin/TA223738
  remotes/origin/master

(TA216441) $ git ls-remote --heads origin
  hash-1 refs/heads/DE18756_2
  hash-2 refs/heads/TA212425
  hash-2 refs/heads/TA219346
  hash-3 refs/heads/TA220305
  hash-4 refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `git branch -a` lists all local and tracking branches, both of which exist *locally*, on your machine.  Here is what I got when I ran `git branch -a`:

```
master
branch1
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/branch1
```

However when you run `git ls-remote --heads origin` it lists the *remote* head references in your repo.  For the same repo, this is what I saw:

```
b9e515799... refs/heads/master
9a7faebd1... refs/heads/branch1
```

The repo only has the true remote branches, which is what you are actually synching with when you use things like `git pull`.

Comment: It seems that branch was removed, but git branch -a does not check if branch really exist on remote.

Comment: @BartekWichowski: correct: `git branch -a` runs locally and never contacts another Git. `git ls-remote` calls up the other Git and asks it questions. Note that if you like, you can run `git fetch --prune origin` to have your Git call up the Git at `origin`, download any new commits, update your local copies of things, and—this is the "prune" part—*remove* any remote-tracking branches you have for branches they no longer have, i.e., "prune" your `origin/*` remote-tracking branches.

Comment: @BartekWichowski (continued) If you want this to happen *by default*, there is a setting for that. Search [the `git config` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for the word "prune".